# Using Google spreadsheet without authentication

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-data-api

All,
I have an application that is built on GAE, I want to use google spreadsheet (data) API to expose some reports. To do so I've been reading https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ and trying to adopt it to my needs.
In my case really users who are looking at the reports are already authenticated by my application so I don't want to use OAuth 1.0 or 2.0 to authenticate them again. My use case is very simple.
- Users login to my application
- Then click on a link
- I generate a report in shape of a google spreadsheet and redirect user to the report page.
As I'm reading the documentation I can't figure how to do this without getting the user to authenticate again. Please note I don't want to create a document in user's google doc folder, I want to create one in my folder and have the to see it.

Thanks for your pointers.
Amir

Added: I was thinking about this and another challenge I guess is I have to adda document to my folder for each report and share it?! I was hoping I can simply stream the report to user's browser but I guess that's out of question!

Comment: FYI: If you create a Google document and then physically remove it from your "Drive folder" (if you have Google drive) it will no longer show up in your Google docs folder but it will still be accessible and editable by its unique URL although appearing to be invisible in the Google Drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the Google Doc in your own folder, then your authentication is what would be required on the backend, with a sharing level of public.

Comment: As you have the user's email address, you could use the API to grant access (view or edit) to them if you didn't want to make it public.

Comment: Neill, can you provide more info on your solution? maybe a sample code or sudo code?

Comment: Amir, I don't. All of that's provided in the Google Docs API. I've looked into it, and generated basic spreadsheets, but don't have the code. I like Greg's suggestion to avoid making public. Your Google API code should work the same in any container, including GAE. You might want to try https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ discussions.